# An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling"

Tags: eclipse

How do I resolve the above reported Eclipse error message?  Additional details are given below.

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2843)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$11.run(JavaModelManager.java:2749)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1873)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:3886)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

**Session Data**

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_08-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ravisankars/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ravisankars/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Answer (score 0):

**I did the following:**

1) Close eclipse

2) Delete everything from the subfolder 
*\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects* in my workspace. In my case this was
folder *C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects*.

3) Restart eclipse

**I also set my M2_REPO classpath variable in eclipse (this is a maven based project):**

4) In eclipse, select Window - preferences - java - build path - classpath variable - new

5) Set name=M2_REPO

6) Set path=*the path to your .m2 folder* (you will need to find your .m2 folder and use the correct path for your environment, in my case is was *C:\Users\pondolal\.m2\repository*).

7) Restart eclipse

8) Clean and build projects

Comment: This messed up all my projects. I just lost HOURS OF WORK.