# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources"

Tags: eclipse

How do I resolve the above reported error message?  Additional details are given below:

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2843)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1878)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2691)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2855)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClasspathChange.generateDelta(ClasspathChange.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2052)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2740)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2019)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaScriptCore.java:2655)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

**Session Data**

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_08-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ravisankars/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/ravisankars/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208991/an-internal-error-occurred-during-initializing-java-tooling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few things had happened since I first installed Eclipse, like (a) installing / uninstalling plugins (b) upgrading the IDE without correspondingly upgrading the workspace.  Since the history has become complex, troubleshooting also got trick.  Fresh installation along with importing the code base again, fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I did (though I recommend uninstalling and re-installing your plugins first as previously posted by @Rajkumar) is to remove the builder causing the issue. MyProject -> Properties -> Builders ...[Troublesome Builder]... Remove.

It is a short run solution, you are only circumventing the real issue, but for me, it did what I needed it to for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Problem like happens if you have to many resources file like java scripts in your eclipse project. The solution is to remove the java script nature from project facets or disable the java script validation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you go into all the trouble of uninstalling and installing again; if you haven't done any special action with your plug-ins, you may want to try the following which is fast and simple:

1. Close the project(s)
2. Open the project(s)
3. Restart eclipse

For me after this it is working. This is solving a lot of unaccepted issues that may occurred with older eclipse versions too.